# Javascript How to get only the first number of an element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this value : `valBnb = Number(bnbPrice.times(f.lpTotalInQuoteToken))`
When I console this value I have this :

```
35 000
45 000
37 000
```

At each Iteration, I have this 3 values. How can I get only the first one (35 000) ?

Comment: Please upload more code

Comment: Please mention your response/console structure. question needs little more explanation.